# webform telephone field validation fails

Tags: 8, webforms

I am using webform-8.x-5.0 and created a telephone field with international phone numbers support. Before submitting the form if i enter some number like "+91fdfgdfg45646" it shows "Invalid phone number" (which i am not sure if it is a valid number or not). But when I submit the form it gets submitted. The issue is if it is invalid, the form should not have been submitted. Please suggest a solution. The form should not be submitted if it is invalid number.

Thanks in advance

Image for reference:
[image: Invalid phone number]

Answer (score 1):

The international phone number element is only a client-side enhancement which is using the [International Telephone Input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) library.

To validate the phone number via server-side validation you would need write custom code and to use a PHP library like https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Comment: The form shouldn't really submit if validation fails though (if it's using JS to validate the form it can also use JS to stop the submission) would that be a bug that needs to be raised or is this expected/inevitable behaviour?

Comment: I think this should be addressed the International Telephone Input library but I would be open to committing enhancements to the Webform module's 'Advance Telephone' element's server-side validation.

Comment: Admittedly I don't know the specifics of the implementation, but I wouldn't expect a JS filter library to stop a form submitting itself. I'd expect it to provide a boolean response, on demand, to the question "is this field valid", and then for my code to decide whether or not the form should be submitted based on that. Probably a discussion for the issue queue though. Might have some tie later, if I do I'll chuck a patch up